How to get current window?
I have problem. I have code in MAUI -> Blazor.
In Blazor must be two buttons:
1 - create new window
2 - show alert in current window.
And Idk how to find current Window. if I use Application.Current.MainPage -> it's will be reference to first window.
But I want show alert in current window.
example of code:

@page "/" 
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web


@inject IJSRuntime JS

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CreateNewWindow">Create new window</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ShowAlert">Show alert!</button>
    </div>
</div>



@code {

    private async Task ShowAlert()
    {
        Page? currentWindow = Application.Current.MainPage;
        if (currentWindow != null)
        {
            await currentWindow.DisplayAlert("Good", "Nice", "Test");
        }
    }

    private async Task CreateNewWindow()
    {
        var newWindow = new Window(new MainPage());
        (Application.Current as App).OpenWindow(newWindow);
    }
}




How can I get instance of current window in which I click to button?
enter image description here
I expected that you help me)


How can I get instance of current window in which I click to button?

For the button is in the razor page, I can't find any way to get the current instance of the window or page. But for a workaround, you can add the reference of the MainPage into the razor page.

Using the Static member (needn't to consider the memory leak because there is only a mainpage in a window):

In the MainPage:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static Page Instance;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Instance = this;
        }
       
    }

In the Razor page:
@code {
    private async Task ShowAlert()
    {
       await MainPage.Instance.DisplayAlert("Good", "Nice", "Test");
    }


Passing the page as parameter:

In the xaml:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiBlazorWindow.Components.Pages"
             x:Class="MauiBlazorWindow.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">

    <BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent x:Name="root"  Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Home}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>

</ContentPage>

In the code behind:
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            root.Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"CurrentPage",this }
            }; 
        }
       
    }

In the razor page:
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Page CurrentPage { get; set; }
    private async Task ShowAlert()
    {
       await CurrentPage.DisplayAlert("Good", "Nice", "Test");
    }

